# in one collection there is multiple name may be having different value, how we find those name having diff. value in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In a collection, there are multiple records having the same `name` value but may have different `person_id` values.

I want to find the `name` having all the different `person_id` values

Sample collection records

```
[{
    _id:"f750a7e5-0645-4683-aab8-23f7b3d754f6", 
    name: "Aditya", 
    person_id: 1800
},
{
    _id: "c35bad16-a092-4868-9427-a51bc485a108", 
    name: "Aditya", 
    person_id: 1800 
},
{
    _id: "2469a3ac-d7df-4e31-95ba-64ddb76cda4b", 
    name: "Aditya", 
    person_id: 1212
},
{
    _id: "ee4c8d2e-1ea8-4efb-b378-0420499f429e", 
    name: "mita", 
    person_id: 1000
},
{
    _id:"ee4c8d2e-1ea8-4efb-b378-0420499f429e", 
    name: "mita", 
    person_id: 100
}]
```

Excepted output for `name: "Aditya"`

```
[{
    _id: "c35bad16-a092-4868-9427-a51bc485a108", 
    name: "Aditya", 
    person_id: 1800 
},
{
    _id: "2469a3ac-d7df-4e31-95ba-64ddb76cda4b", 
    name: "Aditya", 
    person_id: 1212
}]
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the Question [Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$group` query to group all the documents that have the same name and create a set that will contain the distinct ids and then count the distinct values count.

```
db.sample.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
            _id: "$name", 
            person_ids: {$addToSet: "$person_id"}
        }
},
{
    $project: {
            count: {$size: "$person_ids"}, 
            person_ids: 1
        }
},
{
    $match: {count: {$gt: 1}}
}])
```

Output

```
{ "_id" : "mita", "person_ids" : [ 1000, 100 ], "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Aditya", "person_ids" : [ 1212, 1800 ], "count" : 2 }
```

**OR**

If you don't want the count then you can simply use `$group` only like this

```
db.sample.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
                _id: "$name", 
                persons: {$addToSet: "$person_id"}
            }
    }])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : "mita", "persons" : [ 1000, 100 ] }
{ "_id" : "Aditya", "persons" : [ 1212, 1800 ] }
```

For more details on `$group` you can visit the official docs. Here is the link: [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Comment: I am not searching for a specific name, if there is huge data then how I get all data having the same name but different IDs?

Comment: Sorry @SatyamGupta didn't get the question earlier, I have updated my answer